# Report pyparsing syntaxError while catkin_make

Tags: python, cmake, ros

I met a strange problem when using catkin_make with python function enabled in cmakelists.txt, which is shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(transmit)
set(Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/python3.6m")
set(Python3_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so")
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/python3.6")
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        rospy
        sensor_msgs
        std_msgs
        )
catkin_package(
        CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs
)

include_directories(
        include
        ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(transmit src/transmit.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${Python3_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

After catkin_make, the terminal reported error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/catkin_make", line 13, in <module>
    from catkin.builder import apply_platform_specific_defaults  # noqa: E402
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.py", line 54, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .package import _get_package_xml
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 44, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.condition import evaluate_condition
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/condition.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pyparsing as pp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyparsing/__init__.py", line 100
    major: int
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems that an official python package has syntax error, which is strange.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using ROS Melodic which officially supports Python2.7 by default. The package you’re trying to use is written for Python3, but it’s trying to be imported as a Python2.7 script. To fix this you’ll need to either find the Python2.7 version of the package, or upgrade everything to ROS Noetic, which targets Python3.x.

The second option would technically be the correct one since you really shouldn’t be using Python2 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

pyparsing 2.4.7 is compatible with Python 2.